# Android and SQLite: "nested" getReadableDatabase

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

In my Android app I use the following code to access db:

```
public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
/* ... */
}

public class DbManager {

    private DbHelper helper = null;

    public DbManager(Context context) {
        helper = new DbHelper(context);
    }

    public void method1(bool cond) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getReadableDatabase();

        /* operate on db... */

        if (cond) method2();

        /* operate on db... */

        db.close();
    }

    public void method2() {
        /* see below */
    }

}
```

`method1` and `method2` can be called independently from outside the class. In addition, there are situations where `method1` must call `method2`.

In `method2` I need a db instance, so I should call `SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getReadableDatabase();`.
This is ok if `method2` is not called by `method1`. On the other hand, if I call it from `method1`, I create a db handle twice.

Is this ok?

I think I can avoid this situation this way:

```
public void method2(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    SQLiteDatabase locDb;

    if (db == null) {
        locDb = helper.getReadableDatabase();
    } else {
        locDb = db;
    }

    /* ... */

    if (db == null) locDb.close();
}
```

then in `method1` I will use `method2(db);` while from outside I will use `method2(null);`

Does it all make sense? Or I should simply ignore the fact that i'm creating "nested" db instances? How does this impact on performances with higher "nesting" levels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest issue is probably closing the database, it is inefficient to unnecessarily close and open the database.

All you need to do is get the database (getReadableDatabase or getWritableDatabase *(both will under most circumstances return a writable database)*). It will returns the same object, unless the database has been closed, when it then goes though the process of opening the database.

- This will be the same object returned by getWritableDatabase() unless some problem, such as a full disk, requires the database to be opened read-only. In that case, a read-only database object will be returned. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper#getReadableDatabase().

However, perhaps consider :-

```
public class DbManager {

   private DbHelper helper = null;
   private SQLiteDatabase db = null; //<<<<< ADDED

   public DbManager(Context context) {
      helper = new DbHelper(context);
      db = helper.getWritableDatabase(); //<<<<< ADDED
   }

   public void method1(boolean cond) {

      /* operate on db... */

      if (cond) method2();

      /* operate on db... */
   }

   public void method2() {
      /* operate on db... */
      
   }
}
```

Of course you may wish to also consider using a singleton approach to the DbHelper, then multiple DbManager instances, would only have the single DbHelper instance

e.g. you could have something like :-

```
public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

   private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "whatever";
   private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
   /* ... */

   /* don't allow construction of a DbHelper by making the constructor private */
   private DbHelper(Context context) {
      super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
   }

   volatile static private DbHelper instance = null;
   public static DbHelper getInstance(Context context) {
      if (instance == null) {
         instance = new DbHelper(context);
      }
      return instance;
   }


   @Override
   public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {

   }

   @Override
   public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

   }
}
```

along with

```
public class DbManager {

   private DbHelper helper = null;
   private SQLiteDatabase db = null;

   public DbManager(Context context) {
      helper = DbHelper.getInstance(context);
      db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
   }

   public void method1(boolean cond) {

      /* operate on db... */

      if (cond) method2();

      /* operate on db... */
   }

   public void method2() {
      /* see below */

   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you MikeT. If I understand correctly, with the singleton approach a handle to db is created only once, "as writable", the first time I instantiate DbManager, and is never closed. Should I manually close db somewhere else in the app (on closing for example) or this is done automatically?

Comment: @Desti, yep. No need to manually close App clean-up would do this. Except if using WAL mode when closing should checkpoint (write ALL the written ahead data, stored in the -wal file, to the database). You'd probably want this to backup the database file (rather than two files (the database file and the -wal file (same as db file but suffixed with -wal))).